# MySQL: Query UNION, JOIN with conditional WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

Say we have the following tables, employee and payroll_slip:

Table: employee

```
 id_employee | name_employee |
    ============|===============|
    1           | john          |
    2           | doe           |
    3           | alex          |
```

Table: payroll_slip

```
id_slip | id_employee | month_slip | year_slip |
========|=============|============|===========|
1       | 1           | 01         | 2016      |
2       | 2           | 01         | 2016      |
3       | 1           | 02         | 2016      |
4       | 2           | 02         | 2016      |
5       | 1           | 03         | 2016      |
6       | 3           | 03         | 2016      |
```

And we want to get the following result where `month_slip = '03'` AND `year_slip = '2016'`

```
id_employee | month_slip | year_slip | status_slip
============|============|===========|============
1           | 03         | 2016      | paid
2           | 03         | 2016      | unpaid
3           | 03         | 2016      | paid
```

I tried this query:

```
SELECT 
a.id_employee, 
payroll_slip.month_slip, 
payroll_slip.year_slip, 
IF(a.id_employee=payroll_slip.id_employee, 'paid', 'unpaid') AS status_slip
    FROM    (
                SELECT id_employee FROM employee
                UNION 
                SELECT id_employee FROM payroll_slip
            ) a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN payroll_slip ON a.id_employee = payroll_slip.id_employee
    LEFT OUTER JOIN employee ON a.id_employee = employee.id_employee
    WHERE payroll_slip.month_slip = '03' AND payroll_slip.year_slip = '2016'
```

Any suggestion for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try having a cross join:

```
 SELECT X.id_employee, X.month_slip, X.year_slip
    , CASE WHEN Y.id_employee IS NULL THEN 'Unpaid' ELSE 'Paid' END AS status_slip
 FROM (
    SELECT A.id_employee, B.month_slip, B.year_slip
    from employee A
    cross join (
        select '03' AS month_slip, '2016' AS year_slip 
    ) B
 ) X
 LEFT JOIN payroll_slip Y
 ON X.id_employee = Y.id_employee
    AND X.month_slip = Y.month_slip
    AND X.year_slip = Y.year_slip
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT e.id_employee, '03' AS month_slip, '2016' AS year_slip,
    CASE WHEN p.id_employee IS NOT NULL THEN 'paid' ELSE 'unpaid' END AS status_slip
FROM employee e LEFT JOIN payroll_slip p
    ON e.id_employee = p.id_employee AND p.month_slip = '03' AND p.year_slip = '2016'
```

The trick here is to move the restrictions on the `month_slip` and `year_slip` *inside* the `JOIN` condition, rather than in the `WHERE` clause.

**Follow the link below for a running demo:**

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4bc0d1/3)

Comment: `month_slip` and `year_slip` for `id_employee = 2` will be `null`.

Comment: Nice catch...didn't see that

Comment: id_employee 2 will show if you run the query as written. If you mixed up `LEFT join` and used an `INNER join` or just `JOIN` then ie_employee 2 will not show.